# Problem running a Unity App in Background

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have just a small Application running an mqtt client & an ntrip client, which should have cross-platform support. Therfore I decided to go with Unity.

The app is running fine, but however the RunInBackground flag is not working for Android/IOS, after some research I read about, either run a Service as Plugin or "hacking" the exported Android Project by commenting out `mUnityPlayer.pause();` in Androids `OnPause()`.

I decided to go with the second option, since I didn't want to write an extra Android project for the mqtt and ntrip client to run in background as service.

However, after applying this "hack" nothing changed on the behaviour.

The app is still paused whenever I minimize it.

Does anyone have an advice, how to get it done with such a minimal change, or will I have to write a complete android application?

Comment: Make sure the app isn't being killed by the OS, if you don´t have stock android where you are testing, it may be the cause. Many developers have a hard time making an app work in background.

Comment: Ok I am not using an stock android.
What do you mean by killed? I logged the OnPause() and onDestroy() Events and I can only see that it gets to OnPause() not destroy?

Comment: Okey I thought your app was being killed (freed up from memory). Sometimes roms kill your app in background, (this website tells you how to avoid it  https://dontkillmyapp.com/)
You need to do more complex changes to do what you want, I don't think there's an easy way.

Comment: ok. then I will have to look into android a bit deeper :)
thanks anyway!

Comment: how did you achieve running you app running in background with unity

Comment: unfortunately its not possible to do this directly via unity. You have to implement the stuff you want to run in background in a native lib and call the lib in unity